# INDEX/MATCH multiple criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, match

**I am making up a tab with data ordered vertical, and need to index and match with another tab where the data is ordered horizontal.**

I have tried to do a tutorial on this, and it seemed do-able. I made an array formula which I think captures all criteria to get the right value, but it gives me `#N/A.`

I figured I'd use the following three criteria:

- Row name (in this case "XXX")
- Family name (in this case "Amphipoda")
- "Count", as that's the exact row I want to get a result from.

***The formula is:***

`{=INDEX(Family_Distribution!A1:Z271,MATCH(1,(Family_Distribution!C1:X1=all_Results_Habitats!A38)*(Family_Distribution!A1:A271=all_Results_Habitats!B1)*(Family_Distribution!B:B="Count"),0),3)}`

**The table to perform the indexing and matching with looks like this:**

[image: Table to index and match with]

**The table where I place the formula looks like this:**

[image: Table to place the formula in]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the formula with the "Evaluate Formula" on the "Formulas" tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try, no array entry needed:

```
=INDEX(Family_Distribution!$C$2:$Z$271,MATCH(1,INDEX((Family_Distribution!$A$2:$A$271=all_Results_Habitats!B1)*(Family_Distribution!$B$2:$B$271="Count"),),0),MATCH(all_Results_Habitats!A38,Family_Distribution!$C$1:$Z$1,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to retype all of that to test, so this is untested:

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(Family_Distribution!A:Z,MATCH($B$1,Family_Distribution!A:A,0)+MATCH("Count",Family_Distribution!B:B,0)-1,0),INDEX(Family_Distribution!A:Z,MATCH($B$1,Family_Distribution!A:A,0),0),B38)
```